# as3 random array - randomize array - actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, random

How do you randomize an array using actionscript 3?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a short version using Array.sort() function:

```
var arr : Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function randomize ( a : *, b : * ) : int {
    return ( Math.random() > .5 ) ? 1 : -1;
}

trace( arr.sort( randomize ) );
```

If you don't get "enough" randomness you can sort twice :)

**EDIT - explanation line by line:**

For `Array` class method `sort()` you can pass not only sort options like `Array.CASEINSENSITIVE, Array.DESCENDING` and so on but also your own custom compare function reference (a callback) that accepts two parameters (two elements from array to compare). From AS3 documentation:

> A comparison function should take two arguments to compare. Given the elements A and B, the result of compareFunction can have a negative, 0, or positive value:
>
> - A negative return value specifies that A appears before B in the sorted sequence.
> - A return value of 0 specifies that A and B have the same sort order.
> - A positive return value specifies that A appears after B in the sorted sequence.

Note: compare function parameters might be typed (if your array is typed) and have any name you want eg.:

```
function compareElements ( elementA : SomeClass, elementB : SomeClass ) : int;
```

This method is very useful when you need to sort array elements by their special properties. In randomization case `compareFunction` randomly returns `-1, 0` or `1` and makes array elements to switch their places (indices). I have found that better randomization (in my subjective and mathematically untested opinion) is when method returns only `-1` and `1`. Also have in mind that sorting function with custom compare function [doesn't compare elements sequentially](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/archive/index.php3/t-155186.html) so in some special cases randomization results may differ from what you might expect.

Comment: I think `(Math.random() < .5) ? -1 : 1` is better.

Comment: Agreed, more efficient and there's no need to round

Comment: This is pretty AWESOME. Can you break down the lines and explain what they are doing? Like what is the ( a : *, b : * ) and the sort etc..

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way that will also allow you to randomize the array in place, if you need that, and it will not make you create more then a single copy of your original array.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class RandomizeArrayExample extends Sprite
    {
        public function RandomizeArrayExample()
        {
            super();
            testDistribution();
        }

        private function testDistribution():void
        {
            var hash:Object = { };
            var tester:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            var key:String;

            for (var i:int; i < 1e5; i++)
            {
                randomize(tester);
                key = tester.join("");
                if (key in hash) hash[key]++;
                else hash[key] = 1;
            }
            for (var p:String in hash) trace(p, "=>", hash[p]);
        }

        private function randomize(array:Array):Array
        {
            var temp:Object;
            var tempOffset:int;
            for (var i:int = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                tempOffset = Math.random() * i;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[tempOffset];
                array[tempOffset] = temp;
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this very helpful. I hope it can help you too.

```
// Array to Randomize
var firstArray:Array = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"];
trace(firstArray); // Prints in order

var newArray:Array = new Array();
function randomizeArray(array:Array):Array
{
    var newArray:Array = new Array();

    while (array.length > 0)
    {
        newArray.push(array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length), 1));
    }

    return newArray;
}

var randomArray:Array = randomizeArray(firstArray);
trace(randomArray); // Prints out randomized :)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an alternative requirement where i wanted to randomly insert lots of source arrays into a target array randomly. Like Rytis i'm a big fan of the forEach, map and sort functions on Arrays.

```
var randomInsert:Function = function callback(item:*, index:int, array:Vector.<MyItem>):void
{
    var j:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * targetArray.length);
    targetArray.splice(j,0,item);                   
}

targetArray = new Vector.<MyItem>();
sourceArray1.forEach(randomInsert, this);
sourceArray2.forEach(randomInsert, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an easier function. Works also on multidimensional arrays

```
function randomizeArray(array:Array):Array
{
    var newArray:Array = new Array();
    while (array.length > 0)
    {
        var mn=Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)
        newArray[newArray.length]=array[mn]
        array.splice(mn,1)
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need your array to be shuffled (your elements can not repeat). You could use this function:

```
/**
 * Shuffles array into new array with no repeating elements. Simple swap algorithm is used.
 */
public function shuffleArray(original:Array):Array
{
    // How many swaps we will do
    // Increase this number for better results (more shuffled array, but slower performance)
    const runs:int = original.length * 3;
    var shuffled:Array = new Array(original.length);

    var i:int;
    var a:int;
    var b:int;
    var temp:Object;

    // Copy original array to shuffled
    for(i=0; i<shuffled.length; i++){
        shuffled[i] = original[i];
    }

    // Run random swap cycle 'runs' times
    for(i=0; i<runs; i++){
        // There is a chance that array element will swap with itself,
        // and there is always small probability it will make your shuffle
        // results not that good, hence try to experiment with
        // different runs count as stated above
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * original.length);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * original.length);

        // Swap messages
        temp = shuffled[a];
        shuffled[a] = shuffled[b];
        shuffled[b] = temp;
    }

    return shuffled;
}
```

Usage:

```
var testArray:Array = ["Water", "Fire", "Air", "Earth"];
trace(shuffleArray(testArray).concat());
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I randomize my array of 36 cards for a memory game

```
const QUANT_CARTAS: int = 36;

//get the 36 numbers into the array
for (var i: int = 0; i < QUANT_CARTAS; i++)
{
    cartas.push(i);
}

//shuffles them =)
for (var moeda: int = QUANT_CARTAS - 1; moeda > 0; moeda--)
{
    var pos: int = Math.floor(Math.random() * moeda);
    var carta: int = cartas[moeda];
    cartas[moeda] = cartas[pos];
    cartas[pos] = carta;
}
// and add them using the random order...

    for (i = 0; i < QUANT_CARTAS; i++)
{
    var novaCarta: Carta = new Carta();
    novaCarta.tipoCarta = cartas[i];
    etcetcetc.............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

choose random string from array

```
function keyGenerator(len:Number):String
{
    function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
    {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }
    var hexArray = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'];
    var key = "";
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        key +=  hexArray[randomRange(0,hexArray.length-1)];
    }
    return key;
}
```

usage:

```
trace(keyGenerator(16));
```