# How to randomly swap shapes' positions in specific locations

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, position, sprite, addchild

HELP! I'm trying to create a memory game and I'm not too sure how to randomize the shapes' positions in set x and y locations. They can't overlap so they must be randomized in 12 different locations every time the user starts the program.

Answer (score 0):

Store your x and y positions in arrays

```
var xArray=new Array();
var yArray=new Array();

xArray[0]=50;
yArray[0]=50;
xArray[1]=100;
yArray[1]=50;
xArray[2]=150;
yArray[2]=50;
...
```

Create an array of values for each of your shapes

```
var valueArray=new Array(0,1,2.....);
```

Shuffle the values in this array - [as3 random array - randomize array - actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980657/as3-random-array-randomize-array-actionscript-3)

Set you shape's positions

```
shape0.x=xArray[valueArray[0]];
shape0.y=yArray[valueArray[0]];
shape1.x=xArray[valueArray[1]];
shape1.y=yArray[valueArray[1]];
shape2.x=xArray[valueArray[2]];
shape2.y=yArray[valueArray[2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):Number
{
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) return -1;
    else return 1;
}

// Push 12 positions as new Point() in an array.
var positions:Array = [ new Point(12, 42), new Point(43, 56), new Point(43,87) ]; // ...add 12 positions
var mcs:Array = [mc1, mc2, mc3]; // ...add 12 mcs

positions.sort(randomSort);

// link randomized position to MovieClips:
for (var i:int = 0, l:int = positions.length; i < l, i++ ) {
    var mc:MovieClip = mcs[i];
    var point:Point = positions[i];
    mc.x = point.x;
    mc.y = point.y;
}
```