# AS3: Creating A Multiple Choice game with Random Questions

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to create a multiple choice game that asks questions in random? or any quiz game in which the questions comes in random, just using only flash and actionscript 3.0? Any answers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "asks questions in random." That's an incomplete sentence.  Do you mean, in random order?  Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong grammar...yes..that's what I meant..In such a way that the questions don't really comes in a particular order but in random order..Is that possible by just using flash and as3? thanks for the reply by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Just randomize Quiz, you should create an Array that stores stuff like quiz sentence . and this array shuffle using a following algorthims.

```
var quiz:Array = 
[
  "1+1 = ?",
  "2+2 = ?",
  "3+3 = ?",
  "4+4 = ?",
  "5+5 = ?"
];

function shuffleArray($arr:Array):Array
{
    var l:Number = $arr.length - 1;

    for (var it:uint = 0; it<l; it++)
    {
        var r:int = Math.round(Math.random() * l);
        var tmp:String = $arr[it];
        $arr[it] = $arr[r];
        $arr[r] = tmp;
    }
    return $arr;
}

var refreshQuiz:Array = shuffleArray(quiz);

trace(refreshQuiz);
```

If you want build a really quiz game, refer a following skeleton code. This code show to user random quiz. Enter each answer in the Textfield, then the correct answer, the correct answer. Otherwise, it shows the wrong answer is a simple game.

```
var quizModel:Array = [{q:"1+1 = ?", a:"2"}, {q:"5+5 = ?", a:"10"}, {q:"2+2 = ?", a:"4"}, {q:"6+6 = ?", a:"12"},{q:"8-7 = ?",a:"1"}];

var user_ans:Array = new Array();
var newQuizModel:Array = shuffleArray(quizModel);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, go);

function shuffleArray(arr:Array):Array
{
    var l:Number = arr.length - 1;

    for (var it:uint = 0; it<l; it++)
    {
        var r:int = Math.round(Math.random() * l);
        var tmp:Object = arr[it];
        arr[it] = arr[r];
        arr[r] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}

var index:int = 0;
questions_txt.text = newQuizModel[index]["q"];
var userAnswer:String = "";
function go(k:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (k.keyCode != Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        return;
    }

    userAnswer = answers_txt.text;

    if (userAnswer == newQuizModel[index]["a"])
    {
        answers_txt.text = "Your answer is correct!";
    }
    else
    {
        answers_txt.text = "Your answer is wrong";
        return;
    }

    index++;
    index%= quizModel.length;
    showQuiz(index);
}

function showQuiz(idx:int):void
{
    questions_txt.text = newQuizModel[idx]["q"];
}

showQuiz(index);
```

Comment: If you satisfied. plz clicked the check button :)

Comment: bitmapdata..I  just tried your code and it works perfectly fine..thanks for that...I forgot to ask this but can I associate the quiz game with pictures or even swf/movieclips? I mean for example, There's a question:"What is this bird?"..And there's a picture of a bird together with the question..Do you have any idea How I can add it on the code? Am I going to add it on the array? I'll appreciate any answers...

Comment: It's very easy for me. are you have resource? if have, give to me url. i'll make it.

Comment: Sorry but I have no resources as of now..Can you just give me a simple example were in a picture is being used? like what are the codes to put and where to put it? p.s. (Can you use the code you just given or any similar to that? ..because I just happened to use and run it successfully..hope you understand)

Answer (score 0):

So your question boils down to random sorting an Array is AS3.  There's another [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980657/as3-random-array-randomize-array-actionscript-3) about this, but the summary is:

```
var arr:Array = [ item1, item2, item3, item4, ... ];
arr.sort(function():int { return Math.random()<.5 ? -1 : 1; });
```

Where arr is your array of question items - could be Strings, could be Objects with questions and answer details, but that's one way to random-sort an Array.