# Select random elements from an array without repeat in AS2

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-8

I have an array containing 3 variables,i want to randomly pick 2 of them without picking the same element twice,I did find a question by someone trying to do the same thing except they were working with AS3,and their issue was entirely different:[Select random elements from an array without repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339551/select-random-elements-from-an-array-without-repeats)

here's my attempt:

```
var ar:Array=[k,l,m];
var raar:* = ar[Math.floor(ar.length * Math.random())];
```

I'm still new to AS2 and I don't how to utilize certain data types,how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of picking twice an element for your array, you can simply generate once a random index which will be the element that won't be used (picked), like this :

```
var a:Array = [10, 20, 30];
var n:Number = Math.floor(a.length * Math.random());

a.splice(n, 1);     // remove the element with the index n
trace(a);           // for n = 1, gives : 10, 30
```

Hope that can help.